# reading nodes from a file to make a graph -using java

Tags: java, file, graph

the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7 1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:19)
```

I am trying to read a file contet as follows , just like  if the comma appear ,it means there is a direct arrow in the graph !from 3 to 7 there is a direct arrow and from 1 to 4 and so on .

the file.txt content :

```
3,7  1,4 7,8  0,5  5,2  3,0 2,9  0,6   4,9  2,6  6,4  1,5 8,2  9,0  8,3 4,5  2,3  1,6  3,5  7,6
```

the java code :

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication3 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));

    // Read the number of vertices
    String line = inFile.nextLine();
    String[] data=line.split("\\,");
        int part1=Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
    int part2=Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
\*I expect the 2 lines above to work like that :part1=3, part2=7 .but what I noticed there is aproblem about the space character .*/
        while(inFile.hasNext())
    {
        line=inFile.nextLine();
        int index =0;
        int count=0;
        char edges = ',';
        while(index<line.length()) {

            if(line.charAt(index)==edges){
                count++;
            }
            index++;
        }

    }
```

}

.

help me if you can thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You're only splitting the `line` where there is a comma, and you want to split it where there's a space as well. Otherwise `data` will look like this:

```
{"3", "7 1", "4 7", "8 0", ..., "5 7", "6"}
```

And you can't parse `"7 1"` (or any of the ohers containing a space) to `int`.

To fix it, change the delimiter from `"\\,"` to `",|\\s+"`, like this:

```
String[] data=line.split(",|\\s+");
```

Comment: I would suggest to use the regex `"[,\\s]"` so it would split on spacelike characters such as tab.

Comment: @codequestioneer Yes, if the file might use other whitespace characters instead. I figured it probably wouldn't here, but I'll edit my answer just in case. It also looks like there are multiple spaces in a row at some places. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I tried "[,\\s]" but there was a problem too , so I tried the second option String[] data=line.split(",|\\s+"); and it works now , maybe because I used multiple spaces as you said , thank you both @Lonenebula

Comment: @nana I used `"[, ]"` in my answer at first, and codequestioneer suggested to use \s instead of space, which I did. But I also made another fix, noticing the file contained multiple spaces in a row. In any case, consider accepting the answer if it helped.